# form information from form not sending

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, php

Below is the HTML for the form im using.

```
<form action= "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/sendmail.php'; ?>" method="POST" id="contactForm">

    <div class="row alignleft infieldlabel">
        <p class="form_label">Name</p>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="yourname" value="" class="inputtext input_middle required">
    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <div class="row alignleft infieldlabel">
        <p class="form_label">Email</p>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" class="inputtext input_middle required">
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div> 
    <p class="form_label">Select Subject</p>
    <div class="styled-select">
        <select id="subject">
            <option>Personal Injury</option>
            <option>Wrongful Death</option>
            <option>Litigation</option>
        </select>
    </div>  

    <div class="clear"></div>   

    <div class="row infieldlabel">
        <p class="form_label"><?php echo $eto_options["eto_textinput"];?></p>
        <textarea id="message" cols="30" rows="10" name="message" class="textarea textarea_middle required"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="row rowSubmit">
        <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send" class="contact_btnsubmit">                                
    </div>
</form>
```

Im using the following script to try and send the information. The email is just an example, in the actual use I had a correct email address.

```
$email = $_POST['mail@example.com']; 

$to = $email; // email to send to...
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$headers = 'From:' $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: Reply to email' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Also i should note that when i hit the submit button on my form nothing happens, the page doesn't load or anything. Also this is in wordpress thus the random bit of php in the html.

Comment: Try closing input fields like `/>`

Comment: This => `$email = $_POST['mail@example.com'];` is invalid. It should be along the lines of `$email = $_POST['email'];` or `$email = 'mail@example.com'; `

Comment: I tried closing out the input field with /> but it still wouldn't allow the form to send. When i click i still get no response.

Comment: Does the form submit? If yes check @fred -ii-'s comment.

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson Have you tried `<form action= "sendmail.php"` instead? It should work if both files are in the same folder. Otherwise, you may have to do something to the affect of `<form action= "/wp-content/themes/your_theme/sendmail.php"` --- also see my other comment. I helped someone with a similar problem a day or so ago.

Comment: im doing that now and no the form doesn't submit

Comment: @Fred-ii- the first problem is his form is not submitting.

Comment: i cant for the life of me figure out why the form wont send.

Comment: Try re-writing the form with only basic tags, without styling..and close all the tags properly..

Comment: just did that and the form is still not sending.

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson Your headers were the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the headers which threw me an error.

Your headers which contain `Reply-To: Reply to` <= 2x Reply statements

```
$headers = 'From:' $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: Reply to email' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Gave me the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) in...

Here is working code while using this in my test form:

```
<form action= "sendmail.php" method="POST" id="contactForm">
```

PHP

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email']; 
$to = "email@example.com";
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

### FORM USED

**NOTE**: I changed `<select id="subject">` to `<select id="subject" name="subject">`

That way, it will show up as the subject in your email which was not present in your form.

```
<form action= "sendmail.php" method="POST" id="contactForm">

<div class="row alignleft infieldlabel">
    <p class="form_label">Name</p>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="yourname" value="" class="inputtext input_middle required">
</div>

<div class="space"></div>

<div class="row alignleft infieldlabel">
    <p class="form_label">Email</p>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" class="inputtext input_middle required">
</div>

<div class="clear"></div> 
 <p class="form_label">Select Subject</p>
<div class="styled-select">
    <select id="subject" name="subject">
       <option>Personal Injury</option>
       <option>Wrongful Death</option>
       <option>Litigation</option>
    </select>

</div>  


<div class="clear"></div>   

<div class="row infieldlabel">
   <p class="form_label"><?php echo $eto_options["eto_textinput"];?></p>
    <textarea id="message" cols="30" rows="10" name="message" class="textarea textarea_middle required"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="row rowSubmit">
<input type="submit" id="send" value="Send" class="contact_btnsubmit">                                

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: The form is still not sending to the script.

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson I used this as the action in my test form `<form action= "sendmail.php" method="POST" id="contactForm">` You obviously have a path issue to your `sendmail.php`

Comment: if that's the case i should still get an error when the form tries to send to an incorrect url. The form doesn't even try to send.

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson You would have gotten an error yes, with the present headers that you originally posted.

Comment: I didn't get an error, the form makes no attempt to send the information.

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson Have you pasted my code into yours and re-uploaded it to your server, being `sendmail.php`

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson Any chance of knowing the URL?

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson Something just came to mind. Since you're on Wordpress, I think WP has its own `mail()` function called `wp_mail()`. Have you tried using `wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` ?

Comment: Here's the url to the script you wanted me to change

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson I don't see the URL

Comment: http://www.elevocity.com/wordpresstesting/pardue/wp-content/themes/pardue/sendmail.php

heres the script to the page with the form

http://www.elevocity.com/wordpresstesting/pardue/contact

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson Ok, going to check it now.

Comment: I really appreciate you helping me by the way. This is the last thing i have to fix before this site is ready to be launched, besides changing some simple stuff around like the content.

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson You're welcome. Ok so try setting your action to this `<form action="/wordpresstesting/pardue/wp-content/themes/pardue/sendmail.php">`

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson Also, I noticed this at the end of your `submit` button `</input>` remove it.

Comment: No dice, on the answer below the small form he gave allowed the sample to submit.

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson Sorry, I don't follow what you mean.

Comment: the second answer that is on this question allowed the form to submit. only the form in the example though

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson Another thing I noticed which could play tricks on you is this `<form action= "/sendmail.php'" method="POST" id="contactForm">` the extra `'` change it to `<form action= "/sendmail.php" method="POST" id="contactForm">` that IS the problem.

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson I reloaded your form and sent a test email, seemed to have worked.

Comment: Did you use the form on my page?

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson About 5 minutes ago, yes and I used the other submit button instead of the one with the arrow. I used `email@example.com` as an email address.

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson  And as Viraths mentioned about your empty subject name. You probably could use something to the affect of `<select id="subject" name="subject">`

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson What I think is happening with your original Submit button is that it's a "background" image. That could be the fault of it not acting like a submit button.

Comment: OK if i put to forms on the page the second form will submit but only if the first form has a submit button as well, im thinking javascript might be doing something here.

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson I just re-tested it now, and used the bottom arrow button, seems to have gone through. Yeah, there's something really strange happening here.

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson You probably could hide the submit button on top with some CSS, for now, and then `echo` a message once the mail went out too.

Comment: you think like i do :)

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson Also change your `<select id="subject">` to `<select id="subject" name="subject">` --- the option the person chooses will show up as the subject in your email, I just tested my copy now, and it worked.

Comment: @WilliamWilkerson **Added note**. You may want to add this underneath the `mail(...);` => `header('Location: http://www.example.com/thank_you.php'); exit;` or `echo "Thank you, your message has been sent"; exit;` but it's better to do a header redirect, that way you can make the `thank you` page the same look as your Web site. Change `http://www.example.com/thank_you.php` to the Web address you wish it to be.

Answer (score 0):

first try with following basic option and let me know whether this is working. copy paste this following code to your page.

```
<form action= "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/sendmail.php'; ?>" method="POST" id="contactForm">
    Test value:<input type="text" name="test_box" />
    <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send" class="contact_btnsubmit">
</form>
```

Comment: awesome then there is stupid error inside the form. so enter one div at a one time to above basic form and check whether the form is submitted. So eventually you would be able to narrow down where is the error.


Also I noticed that subject select box does not hava a name